# Retry Jenkins build triggered by git push to arbitrary branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to add some very basic functionality that exists in every other modern ci product, but which unfortunately seems to be a completely foreign concept in Jenkins land.

I have the github plugin hooked up, and the git plugin set to build the "inverse" of "origin/master", so that pushing any branch except master triggers a build.

The problem is, if there's a flaky test and the build fails there's no way to restart it in jenkins. I added the Naginator plugin but it rebuilds the last branch that ran, not the branch of the build that you clicked "retry" on. Using the Naginator plugin, it seems that I need the git branch or sha to be a real parameter of the build. But, I can't find a way to set the git branch as a parameter of the build when a build gets triggered.

The only thing I can think of is to split it into two builds that link to the same git repo, and have the second one be a parameterized build that the first one triggers with the GIT_COMMIT value as the parameter. Then, retrying the second one with Naginator should retry it on the same SHA. This isn't a good solution though, it sucks to have to configure 2 builds for every one of my builds.

Does anyone know of a good way to accomplish this? I'm hoping I'm just missing something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately i'm unfamiliar with this exact setup, however the [Git plugin documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin), section *Push notification from repository*, mentions that in the trigger url, the `<commit ID` *is optional. If set, it will trigger a build **immediately, without polling for changes**.*

If there is a built-in "button" in some plugin to issue this manually from inside jenkins UI i don't know, if not that could be a nice feature request.

So, if there really is no easy option aviable yet, as a workaround you could write yourself some script which builds and calls the url for a given branch + commit ID.

> Trigger url format, as found in [Git Plugin docs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin):
>
> `curl http://yourserver/git/notifyCommit?url=<URL of the Git repository>&branches=branch1[,branch2]*][&sha1=<commit ID>]`